# Converting FORTRAN code to MATLAB - references

Tags: matlab, fortran

I am currently working on a research project for my Finance professor, and I am supposed to replicate the results of a previous paper by writing the code in MATLAB. I encountered problems, however, and I asked the authors of the previous paper to send me the source code. The code that they used, however, is in Fortran, and I was wondering if I can convert the code from Fortran to MATLAB, and what references I should use. Thanks!

Comment: All you have to do is learn [tag:Matlab] and rewrite it.

Comment: You can ask specific questions when you run into specific problems.  But no one can give you a useful answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @wallyk I am familiar with MATLAB, but Fortran is an entirely different language for me, which is why I asked if it is indeed possible. I apologize, however, for how general this question is. I'm very much new to Fortran.

Comment: Julio, I know of one article that deals with the topic of modernizing old Fortran code. I guess I could look for it, if you think it would be of any help to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One place to start would be f2matlab from [here](http://engineering.dartmouth.edu/~d30574x/consulting/consultingIndex.html). Follow the README file to get started. f2matlab usually gets you 95% of the way to a working m-file, so you will have to debug the m-file after conversion.

Your code needs to be in fortran90 format first, and you can use Alan Miller's or Metcalf's converter to help with that.

Finally, one of the most difficult things to do is remove the goto's from the fortran code before trying f2matlab. You can look at my page [here](http://engineering.dartmouth.edu/~d30574x/consulting/consulting_gotorefactor.html) discussing goto removal/refactorization with remgoto.

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried running f2matlab, and I get notifications of numerous goto's, which I think the program couldn't convert. I found this program that I used to try to convert the gotos [link] (http://www.polyhedron.com/plusfortdownloads), but I am a bit unsure when I read the resulting code (without running it to f2matlab.)

Comment: The fortran output from plusfort's spag will be numerically identical to the input. And f2matlab cannot convert goto's but spag only gets rid of about 2/3 of the goto's. If you need help with the remaining goto's, I have a program that refactor's the rest. PM me.

Answer (score 1):

The best references would probably be, the books on Fortran and MATLAB (let's say, for someone starting with each, books by Chapman - he's written an introductory book on both, Fortran and MATLAB). I'm not familiar with any works that deal specifically with the problem of rewriting from one to another, although rewriting from Fortran to MATLAB is certanly easier than the other way around.

It also significantly varies with the revision of Fortran that way used in the original code - using Fortran90 and newer revisions, code can be made almost MATLAB like, in terms of shortness and expressiveness. If you have [problem with the syntax](http://www.clear.rice.edu/mech517/F90_docs/tables.pdf) here is one document that compares it, so it's not bad to have it as a reference.

But why not just try to compile (or change a bit, and then compile) the original code as a .dll and try to connect it with MATLAB. That way, you'll certanly lose less in terms of speed, and will probably avoid a whole chapter of problems of numerical instability and testing.